# Maximum sum contiguous subsequence is zero?

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence, dynamic-programming

I am attempting to understand the solution to this problem: "Given a sequence of numbers, find the maximum sum of a contiguous subsequence of those numbers." I have quoted a solution and explanation below.

What I don't understand is, in the line "maxendinghere = max(maxendinghere + s, 0)", why would maxendinghere ever be zero?

```
def max_sum_subsequence(seq):
    maxsofar = 0
    maxendinghere = 0
    for s in seq:
        # invariant: maxendinghere and maxsofar are accurate
        # are accurate up to s
        maxendinghere = max(maxendinghere + s, 0)
        maxsofar = max(maxsofar, maxendinghere)
    return maxsofar
```

The explanation from the website is "Well, essentially maxendinghere is what’s accumulating the subsequences — it keeps rolling the next element into itself. Should this accumulated sum ever become negative we know that the subsequence-which-ends-here we’re currently tracking is worse than the empty subsequence-which-restarts-here; so we can reset our subsequence accumulator, and the first clause of the loop invariant still holds."

What I don't understand is, let's say my sequence is 2 -3 4: why would maxendinghere ever be zero? There is no subsequence whose sum is zero.

(Quotes from: http://wordaligned.org/articles/the-maximum-subsequence-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `2 -3 4`, ask yourself, what is the maximum sum that ends at index 1? `2 - 3` is `-1`. `-3` itself is `-3`. So our maximum sum is then the empty sum, which selects *no* elements and therefore has a sum of 0.

Remember that the empty subsequence is always a possibility, and the identity value of the `sum` operation is 0. So for example, the maximum sum of a contiguous subsequence within `-2 -4 -3` is simply 0, the sum of the empty subsequence.

To validate this:

```
>>> max_sum_subsequence([-2, -4, -3])
0
>>> sum([]) == 0
True
```

To change the algorithm so that the subsequence must have at least length 1, you can do so by changing two lines of code.

First, change the initialization of `maxsofar` to be the first element or `None` if it doesn't exist. Instead of `None`, you can use any default value of your choice. The default value is what gets returned for an empty input sequence.

```
maxsofar = seq and seq[0] or None
```

Second, change the assignment to `maxendinghere` to force it to include the value of at least one element from the sequence:

```
maxendinghere = max(maxendinghere + s, s)
```